# numpy where replace with numpy array depending on condition

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,1,1],[-1,-1,-1]])

print (a)
```

Output:

```
[[ 1  1  1]
 [-1 -1 -1]]
```

I can do:

```
b = np.where(np.mean(a,axis=1) > 0,1,0)

print (b)
```

Which correctly results in:

```
[1 0]
```

But when I do:

```
b = np.where(np.mean(a,axis=1) > 0,np.array([1,1]),np.array([0,0]))

print (b)
```

It results in the same:

```
[1 0]
```

What I want is:

```
[[1 1]
 [0 0]]
```

In verbose, I want to replace elements of ndarray based on mean along axis 1 with array and not single integer. So the output from a 2D array should be a 2D array.

Comment: Do you mean `[[ 1  1]
 [0  0]]` as output?

Comment: Yes sorry. I corrected

Comment: What is this doing in verbose?

Comment: why not just replace 1 with `[1, 1]` 0 with `[0,  0]`.  value array need to be the same shape with condition array

Comment: If you mean np.where(randn.mean(axis=0) > 0,[1,0],[1,0]) that neither works. In fact I want to generate labels from a 2D array. So axis 0 will have a the same length but axis 1 must be different after the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [254]: np.mean(a,axis=1) > 0,np.array([1,1]),np.array([0,0])
Out[254]: (array([ True, False]), array([1, 1]), array([0, 0]))
```

The 3 arguments are (2,) shaped arrays.  They broadcast against each other to return a (2,) array.

The key is, `broadcasting`.  It is picking elements from the 2 arrays based on corresponding elements of the condition.  It is't a wholesale pick between the two.

If the condition is (2,1) shaped, that will broadcast against the (2,) to produce a (2,2) result

```
In [255]: (np.mean(a,axis=1) > 0)[:,None],np.array([1,1]),np.array([0,0])
Out[255]: 
(array([[ True],
        [False]]),
 array([1, 1]),
 array([0, 0]))

In [256]: np.where((np.mean(a,axis=1) > 0)[:,None],np.array([1,1]),np.array([0,0]))
Out[256]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the trick / great explanation!